# Jekyll site folder won't display from site folder

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to create a website for my college's Civic Studio program. It is a portfolio site to showcase their work, based on the *folio theme. (It's also unfinished, I just want to put something up to show the department). Here is all my work so far: https://github.com/woodsarah/civstudio

The site runs fine on the local server, but the _site is broken: images, css, and links don't work. I need  _site to work locally because the final site will be run from the art department's servers, not on Github or anything.

I think something is wrong with the baseurl and how the css and images are linked, but I don't know how to approach the situation.

I'm sure there's a really simple solution to this and I just don't know it. I'm really, really new to Jekyll, and appreciate the patience in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you call **css**, **js** or **img**, use `site.baseurl`.

```
{{ site.baseurl }}/path/to/ressource.js
```